# C# - Somando indices de um array e filtrando por resultados comum

Tags: c#, array

Eu preciso criar um for que vai de 10 a 99 e preciso depois imprimir dentro de um if todos os valores que somados resultando em 11 (por exemplo 56 = 5 + 6 = 11)

ate agora meu código está assim

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 10; i <= 99; i++)
        {
            int[] array = new int[2];  
            for(int j = 0; j < i.ToString()[j]; j++)
            {
                array[j] = int.Parse()[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

mas ja estou batendo cabeça algum tempo e nao consigo encontrar a solução final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parte mais difícil é a separar cada dígito, por exemplo 56 para somar 5 + 6.

Uma forma de fazer isso é converter para `string`, ai é possível tratar cada digito separadamente, para evitar fazer operações matemáticas, e em seguida converter cada dígito pra um tipo numérico para poder somar e validar.

Aqui um exemplo:

```
for (int i = 10; i <= 99; i++)
{
    int soma = 0;

    // primeiro, vamos transformar o número em string
    string numString = i.ToString();

    // agora, passar por cada "dígito" na string
    foreach (char digitoString in numString)
    {
        // conveter para inteiro e somar
        soma += int.Parse(digitoString.ToString());
        
    }

    // se a soma for 11, fazer alguma coisa
    if (soma == 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZdRuhe

Comment: Muito obrigada :D ficou bem mais claro de entender.

Answer (score 1):

Se os números são [inteiros](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.int32) e tiverem até dois dígitos você pode extrair a unidade calculando o resto da divisão do número por 10 usando o [operador `%`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) e extrair a dezena desse número apenas realizando a divisão inteira do número por 10 com o [operador `/`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division).

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for(int i = 10; i <= 99; i++) {
          //Se a unidade i%10 mais dezena i/10 for igual a 11...
          if (i%10 + i/10 == 11) Console.WriteLine(i);                 
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/LUOHhI)</sup>

Outra possibilidade é converter os caracteres numa [`String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0) e usar método de extensão [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) para iterar sobre os seus caracteres os convertendo individualmente em inteiros e posteriormente os somando com [`Enumerable.Sum()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for(int i = 10; i <= 99; i++) {          
          if (i.ToString().Select(c=>c-'0').Sum() == 11) Console.WriteLine(i);                 
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/bh0B6F)</sup>